# Build Failed from Dev to Staging using TFS Release management

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild, staging

I am trying to build a project from dev to staging environment, what all i did was just to merge the changes in dev to staging and trigger a build. but the build got failed even tried multiple times.

Below is the log file shared in google drive. there are no errors mentioned in the log file. Can anyone help me solve this problem.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B85ZmWDiKYHRVmN4MlMxc0ZEd28

Comment: There is a `Build succeeded` and not any errors in your attached log. How did you judge the build is failed?  Did you get any other prompting message in your release management?

Answer (score 0):

I found a error in the log file in the release management, which says that "access denied for appsettings.config" file. I did remove the read only on the folder in the server and it worked. I am not sure of this fix properly, but it did work for me. 
Thanks.